# CollectionView Cells won't be centred in view, no matter what I do

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm having trouble with centering my CollectionView Cells on the Collection View.
This is what I have now, found here on Stackoverflow (but tried few other solutions that did not work):

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    let totalCellWidth = cellWidth * CGFloat(posts.count)
    let totalSpacingWidth = CGFloat(cellSpacing * (posts.count - 1))
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width

    let leftInset = (collectionViewWidth - (totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2
    let rightInset = leftInset

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: rightInset)

}
```

I tried writing my own solutions but nothing worked.

cellWidth, cellHeight and cellSpacing are fixed numbers.
This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: collectionView.pagingEnabled = true

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Thanks, I do have this line, but it is not the problem here. the picture shows where it "snaps" to, I just have trouble centering the cell on the screen.

Comment: when you scroll, or when it just loaded?

Comment: When I scroll, the first and last cells are not centered but they look to be more close to what I want, I tried changing things but nothing worked.

Comment: add header and footer with desired width

Comment: @JohnDoah can you show us how it should look like?

Comment: You need to add contentInsets to left and right. For example collectionView.contentInsets = UIEdgeInset(top: 0, left: (collectionView.frame.width / 2) - (cellWidth / 2), bottem: 0, right: (collectionView.frame.width / 2) - (cellWidth / 2))

Comment: @Elhoej Thanks, I tried that too, tried to modify it, but still, I get the same problem.